# Tkinter label won't output onto a canvas

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I found this code else where and edited it slightly to suit my needs, it's meant to output tkinter labels onto a canvas in way way that I can scroll though, however it doesn't output the labels onto the canvas. The purpose of the code is to provide a GUI for a voice control program I'm build and is meant to output the querys and responses onto the canvas. I am reasonable new to using tkinter. This is using python 3.6.2

```
vscrollbar = Scrollbar(Window, orient=VERTICAL)
vscrollbar.place(x = 1860, y = 210, height = 850, width = 50)
canvas = Canvas(Window, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,yscrollcommand=vscrollbar.set)
canvas.place(x = 10, y = 210, height = 850, width = 1850)
vscrollbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

    # reset the view
canvas.xview_moveto(0)
canvas.yview_moveto(0)

    # create a frame inside the canvas which will be scrolled with it
interior = Frame(canvas)
interior_id = canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=interior,anchor=NW)
file = open('querys.txt').read().split('\n')
num = 10
print(len(file))
for i in range(len(file)):
    Button(interior, text = file[i]).place()
    print(file[i])
    file2 = list(file[i])
    if file2[0] == '0':
        file2.pop(0)
        file2.pop(0)
        file2[0] = file2[0].upper()
        label = Label(interior_id, text = ''.join(file2), bg = 'blue', wraplength = 1000).place(width = 1000, x = 900, y = num)
        num+label.winfo_height()
    elif file2[0] == '1':
        file2.pop(0)
        file2.pop(0)
        file2[0] = file2[0].upper()
        label = Label(interior_id, text = ''.join(file2), bg = 'blue', wraplength = 1000).place(width = 1000, x = 900, y = num)
        num+label.winfo_height()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] as opposed to some relative code.

Comment: For one thing, the labels need to be the child of a widget, not a child of the canvas object id.

Comment: So I would have to set the location to the frame interior instead of interior_id

Comment: Use a tkinter window with canvas on top of it and then, put labels on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
canvas.CreateText()
```

If you want to set a *font color* use fill=" color"